# Is there a SelectionChanging event on a ListBox wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like a SelectionChanging event on a ListBox that I can cancel based on certain conditions...Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to cancel?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 what you mean by cancer?

Comment: @Mustafa Ekici, Not sure what you are talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to get away with doing this inside the SelectedItem

Example:

```
    private string _selectedItem;
    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != WhatIWant)
            {
                return;
            }
            _selectedItem = value; 
        }
    }
```

This way if you dont like the value selected to can just bail, or change to somthing else.

DependancyProperites have a cool little callback (CoerceValueCallback) where you can change the value before it is propogated to the propertyChanged event.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged),
    new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceValue)));

private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

}

private static object CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    if (baseValue != WhatIWasExpecting)
    {
        return WhatIWant;
    }
    return baseValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no event in the stock WPF `ListBox` control that fires before changing the selection that allows you to cancel the change.

However, the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` class, which you receive during a `SelectionChangedEvent`, provides you both the old value (being deselected) and the new value (being selected). You could apply your logic in that event and reset the selection back if it fails.

I think the user might notice the flicker of the selection jumping around, if you take this approach, but AFAIK it's the best you can do without subclassing the control and implementing your own `SelectionChanging` event.